# How to manually mount more than one component into the same DOM node in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3

Just like the title, I try to use the createapp method to build component objects, and then mount to DOM nodes. When there are multiple mounts, all the previous ones are cleared. How can I mount continuously while retaining the previous node, just like "insertAfter" in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple mounts as below.

**index.html in body tag**

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="section1"></div>
</body>
```

**main.js file or other file where you mount app.**

```
const headerApp = createApp({
  /* ... */
})
headerApp.mount('#header')

const sectionApp = createApp({
  /* ... */
})
sectionApp.mount('#section1')
```

Comment: The situation is like this, you need to manually mount a custom map label component to the specified div (label layer), but because it is multiple points, all the label components need to be mounted to the div in batches.

Comment: You can add nested components inside a single mounted.

Comment: That approach is not suitable for my usage scenario, but I solved it with a compromise method, first mount the component to a temporary dom (virtual dom?), and then append the root node of the component to the desired dom, In that way, all components can be mounted in turn.